# Moodle user loggin alert

Tags: php, plugins, moodle

**HelloW!!**
[tag:*(HelloW is hello World)*]

I'm development a system to make a scheduler of disciplines in a moodle to my work. I think publish this soft in GitHub in GPL, But I need to request to my system when a user makes login in moodle.

Example:

Student make login in moodle.

Some plugin or function in PHP send a request for my system.

The Request contains a userID and userCohort, and my system make a scheduler to student by Moodle API.

I know that this function return true if user login complete:
`complete_user_login($user)`

But i need de pass paramenter, someone send links or documentation please or help me here.

Exist some plugin for made it?

*My english stay in progress...*

I don't have any idea to do. I never create a moodle plugin and my system is in NodeJS.
But I understand a little of PHP.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can respond to events in Moodle, there is an event for when a user logs in - `core\event\user_loggedin`

To respond to the event, you could create a local plugin, which then calls your code

The new development docs are at https://moodledev.io/docs/apis/plugintypes/local

The old development docs are at https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins

But also take a look at `yourmoodle/local/readme.txt` for the directory structure

At a bare minimum, your plugin should have the following files

- `local/yourplugin/version.php`
- `local/yourplugin/lang/en/local_yourplugin.php`

To respond to the logged in event, create this file - `local/yourplugin/db/events.php`

With something like this

```
$observers = array(

    array(
        'eventname' => 'core\event\user_loggedin',
        'callback' => 'local_yourplugin_observer::user_loggedin',
    ),
```

Then create this file `local/yourplugin/classes/observer.php`

With something like this

```
class local_yourplugin_observer {
    /**
     * Triggered when 'user_loggedin' event is triggered.
     *
     * @param \core\event\user_loggedin $event
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function user_loggedin(\core\event\user_loggedin $event) {
        global $USER;

        // A user can be in more than one cohort, so you'll need to add some logic here for the cohort you want
        $user_cohorts = $DB->get_records('cohort_members', array('userid' => $USER->id), '', 'cohortid');

        // Or

        $sql = "SELECT cm.cohortid
                FROM {cohort_members} cm
                WHERE cm.userid = :userid";

        $user_cohorts = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, array('userid' => $USER->id));


        // Your code here
    }

}
```

The plugin will be installed when you login as an admin

Comment: Thanks, I thank you very much, I will perform the tests and in the future I will return with feedback.